# Informatica : taking very long time when doing insert

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter, informatica-powerexchange

i have one mapping which just includes one source table and one target table. The source table has 100 columns and around 33xxxx records, i need to use this tool to insert to the target table and the logic is insert only. The version of informatica is 9.6.1 version and Database is SQL Server 2012. 
After i run the workflow, it takes 5x/s to insert. the speed is too slow. I think it may be related to the number of columns

Can anyone help me how to increase the speed?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Are there any indexes on the target table?

Comment: no, there is no indexes on the target table.

Answer (score 0):

I think i know the reason why it happened. It is there are two fields  which are **ntext** field in this table. That's why it takes very long time.

Comment: If that's the case, then it simple means that those fields hold a lot of data. You can try removing the links for those ports to make sure. Try to check the total size of data you're moving.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below options

1) Use **bulk** option for **'Target Load type**' attribute in session if the target table doesn't have any indexes or keys on it

2) If there is any SQL override in the **SOURCE QUALIFIER** try to tune the query

3) Find for '*BUSY*' in the session log and note down the busy percentages of each thread. Based on the thread percentages you will be able to identify the exact thread which is taking more time (Reader, Transformation, Writer)

4) Try to use informatica **partitions** through which you can achieve parallel processing.

Thanks and Regards,

Raj

Answer (score 0):

Consider following points to increase the performance:

1. Increase the **"commit interval"** size in the session level properties.
2. Use the **"bulk load"** in session level properties.
3. You can also use the **"partitioning"** in session level, to do this you need partitioning license.
4. If your source is a database and you are doing sql override in source qualifier transformation , then you can also use the **"Hints"** for increasing the performan